# lua: Can I use string to use variable?

Tags: lua

I want string to use variable.

```
variable1 = "Hello"
a = "variable" .. 1
print(a)
```

but it printed variable1 (of cource), 
Can I print "Hello"(variable1) using variable a?

Comment: You can use table for this. Like @cubic said.

Comment: `print('"Hello"(' .. a .. ')')`  if that is not what you want you should improve your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what [tables](https://www.lua.org/pil/11.html) are for - you can just rewrite your code as

```lua
local variables = {}
variables.variable1 = "Hello"
local a = "variable" .. 1
print(variables[a]) -- prints Hello
```

In fact, global variables (as in your example you seem to be using) are already stored in a table called `_G` (the [global table](https://www.lua.org/pil/15.4.html)), so in your example this would work:

```lua
variable1 = "Hello"
a = "variable" .. 1
print(_G[a])
```

Comment: I don't see the relation between the question and your answer.

Comment: @Piglet Judging from your comment on the question, I'd chalk that up to you misreading the question.